# Qt Creator debug window focus on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, debugging, ubuntu, focus

everyone!

I have this strange issue using Qt Creator in Ubuntu (tested on Ubuntu and XUbuntu). I have a simple console application, say an "Hello world". When runnning the debugger, the console window appears for a moment, then the focus returns to Qt Creator (note: no breakpoint set), so the console will be hidden by the IDE and I have to Alt+TAB to go back it.

Any advice on how to change this behavior?

Side note, then running the app (not debugging), the focus remains on the console window.
Also, in Windows the focus remains always on the console window (both when running and debugging), and that's what I want to achieve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the behavior and think it is a bug.

There is an Option in the Debugger settings *Bring Qt Creator to foreground when application interrupts*. If you uncheck this, Qt Creator stops coming to foreground in all cases.

Comment: Kudos! Unchecking the option fixed the problem. I was concerned that this will stop the focus on IDE when a breakpoint occurs, but it didn't happen, so it's ok. So, as for now, this fixed my problem. As a side question, do you have any idea about what behavior we are missing by unchecking this option?

Comment: I never used the option before. Typically *interrupt* occurs in a program when you press Ctrl + C in command line. But even in the case, Qt Creator comes to foreground, no matter how the option is set.